# How to apply logarithm to JQuery Knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to apply logarithm to jquery knob i want to make the 3 sections in different ratio and make it like 20% , 40%, 40% instead of linear if anybody can help me in my problem 
thanks
heres my work https://jsfiddle.net/v4bfLfbu/23/

```
function emp(v) {
    if ($("#emp").val() <= 5) {
        document.getElementById("dollar1").innerHTML = "$" + ((v) * (3 / 2));
        document.getElementById("emp1").innerHTML = $('#emp').val();
        $('#panel1').show();
        $('#panel2').hide();
        $('#panel3').hide();
        $('#desc').hide();
        $('#emp').trigger('configure', {
            "inputColor"
            "#66CC66",
            'displayInput': 'true',
            "fgColor": "#66CC66"
        }).delay(1000000);
    } else if ($("#emp").val() <= 25 {
            document.getElementById("dollar2").innerHTML = "$" + ((v) * (3 / 2));
            document.getElementById("emp2").innerHTML = $('#emp').val();
            $('#panel1').hide();
            $('#panel2').show();
            $('#panel3').hide();
            $('#desc').hide();
            $('#emp').trigger('configure', {
                'inputColor': '#329ed6',
                "fgColor": "#329ed6",
            });
        } else if ($("#emp").val() < 499) {
            document.getElementById("dollar3").innerHTML = "$" + ((v) * (3 / 2));
            document.getElementById("emp3").innerHTML = $('#emp').val();
            $('#panel1').hide();
            $('#panel2').hide();
            $('#panel3').show();
            $('#desc').hide();
            $('#emp').trigger('configure', {
                'inputColor': '#325969',
                "fgColor": "#325969"
            });
        } else {
            $('#panel1').hide();
            $('#panel2').hide();
            $('#panel3').hide();
            $('#desc').show();
            document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = "Please Contact Payment Evolution\nhttps://paymentevolution.com\n,Contact Us : +1-647-776-7600 \n,Mon-Fri 9am-5pm ET\n";
        }
    }
    $(function a() {
        $('.knob').knob({
            'min': '1',
            'max': '500',
            'displayInput': 'true',
            'displayPrevious': 'true',
            'skin': 'tron',
            'release': emp,
            'change': emp
        });
    });
```

Comment: a single line program ;)

Comment: this is not a correct answer its all my code wheredid you add yours?

Comment: please add some examples of the *"logarithm"*, you want.